# Inconsistent relative path resolution in powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, xml

The following script is used to convert an xml file to the correct format. There are 4 stages:

1. Remove all xml headers
2. Wrap all content in a `testsuites` elements
3. Add an xml header
4. Remove `timestamp` elements from `testsuite` elements

---

```
param (
[string] $inputPath = $(throw "-inputPath is required."),
[string] $outputPath = $(throw "-outputPath is required.")
)

$content = Get-Content $inputPath

$replaced = $content -replace '\<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8" \?>', ""

Write-Output $replaced

$xmlHeader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'

$xmlcontent = $xmlHeader + '<testsuites>' + $replaced + '</testsuites>'

$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($xmlcontent)

$xml.testsuites.testsuite[0].RemoveAttribute('timestamp')
$xml.testsuites.testsuite[1].RemoveAttribute('timestamp')

$xml.Save($outputPath)
```

My problem is this. A relative input path always works. A relative output path always puts the file in `c:\windows\system32`. I realise this is to do with Powershell's default working directory but I'm struggling to explain the input path behaviour to my colleagues.

I call the command like this:

```
xmlscript.ps1 -inputPath 'file.xml' -outputPath 'final.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I expected the root cause of the problem to be the way PS handles current folder concept when it works with built-in cmdlets such as `Get-Content` and objects as `System.Xml`

After some search I found this answer on SO:

> Set-Location (aka cd) in PowerShell does not change the current directory maintained by the OS, so the current directory normally stays wherever it was when you started PowerShell. If you want to change the current directory, you can set the [Environment]::CurrentDirectory property

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822575/saving-an-xml-file-in-powershell-requires-complete-path-why

Check it out, it seems legit for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If all three files are in the same path you can invoke the script this way

```
.\xmlscript.ps1 -inputPath '.\file.xml' -outputPath '.\final.xml
```

Or if you want to save the file `final.xml` in the same path as `file.xml` change the last line of your script to:

```
$savePath = Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent $inpuPath) (Split-Path -Leaf $outputPath)
$xml.Save($savePath)
```